# Как экранировать <br> в Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jinja2

У меня есть поле ввода - textarea. В js, при нажатии shift+enter должен быть перенос строки, как `<br>` (\n как-то неправильно работает). Но если пользователь сам введет `<br>` тогда это будет как текст. Это надо как-то сделать в django.

Comment: `\n как-то неправильно работает` -- как это "неправильно"? У меня всё работает, это вы у себя что-то не так написали, может, вам стоит показать нерабочий код?

Comment: Он делает перенос строки, но не делает расширение по высоте textarea